# PowerShell script will not recognize paths I am using

Tags: windows, powershell

I have directories of files and scripts that my main PS script calls on. In this particular script I am trying to call on the files in the "Data" directory located in the root directory of where the script is located and copy them to another directory. PS keeps complaining that it cant find the directory. The Directory structure goes like this:

```
Root
│  Main Script.ps1
│       
│
└───Data
│   │   ei.cfg
│   │   AutoUnattend.xml
│   └───
└───Scripts
│   │   Script1.ps1
│   │   Script2.ps1 etc.
|   └───           
│
└───Binaries       
    │  Program.exe
    │  Program2.exe etc.
    └───
```

I am trying to tell the script to access Root/Data, Root/Scripts, Root/Binaries.

I have tried setting them up in this way:

```
$ScriptPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Scripts
$BinaryPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Binaries
$DataFolderPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Data
```

because when I use something like this:

```
$ScriptPath="$PSScriptRoot\Scripts"
$BinaryPath="$PSScriptRoot\Binaries"
$DataFolderPath="$PSScriptRoot\Data"
```

it only recognizes one of the directories as root Here is what I have. How can I make all the directories point to the different folders in the root directory properly?

```
#region Declarations, Assemblies and Paths
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }


<# $ScriptPath="$PSScriptRoot\Scripts"
$BinaryPath="$PSScriptRoot\Binaries"
$DataFolderPath="$PSScriptRoot\Data" #>
$ScriptPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Scripts
$BinaryPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Binaries
$DataFolderPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Data

#endregion

#region Check File Paths

$directoyPath="C:\ESD\Mount\Windows\Windows\Panther";
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoyPath))  
{  
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoyPath
    Write-Host "Folder path has been created successfully at: " $directoyPath
    
}
else
{
Write-Host "$directoyPath already exists"
}

$directoyPath="C:\ESD\Deployment";
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoyPath))  
{  
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoyPath
    Write-Host "Folder path has been created successfully at: " $directoyPath
    
    
}
else
{
Write-Host "$directoyPath already exists"
}

$directoyPath="C:\ESD\Deployment\sources";
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoyPath))  
{  
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoyPath
    Write-Host "Folder path has been created successfully at: " $directoyPath
    
    
}
else
{
Write-Host "$directoyPath already exists"
}

#endregion

#region Answer File
$UserResponse= [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like would you like to add an answer file?" , "Force Choose Windows Version" , 4, 48)

if ($UserResponse -eq "YES" ) 
{
    Copy-Item '$PSScriptRoot\Data\AutoUnattend.xml' 'C:\ESD\Deployment\Autounattend.xml'
    Copy-Item '$PSScriptRoot\Data\AutoUnattend.xml' 'C:\ESD\Mount\Windows\Windows\Panther\Autounattend.xml'  
    Write-Host "Answer file named AutoUnnatend.xml created." -ForeGround DarkRed
} 

else 

{ 
    Write-Host "skipping answer file"
}
#endregion

#region EI Config
$UserResponse= [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like would you like to add ei.cfg? This will force the windows installer to prompt you for which version you want to install." , "Force Choose Windows Version" , 4, 48)

if ($UserResponse -eq "YES" ) 
{
    Copy-Item '$PSScriptRoot\Data\ei.cfg' 'C:\ESD\Deployment\sources\ei.cfg'
    Write-Host "Config file named ei.cfg created." -ForeGround DarkRed
} 

else 

{ 
    Write-Host "skipping ei.cfg"
}
#endregion
```

Here is the complaint:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\$PSScriptRoot\Data\Autounattend.xml' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\Answerfile.ps1:64 char:5
+     Copy-Item '$PSScriptRoot\Data\Autounattend.xml' 'C:\ESD\Deploymen ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\syst...utounattend.xml:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\$PSScriptRoot\Data\Autounattend.xml' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\Answerfile.ps1:65 char:5
+     Copy-Item '$PSScriptRoot\Data\Autounattend.xml' 'C:\ESD\Mount\Win ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\syst...utounattend.xml:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

[image]

Comment: If you want that the $variable automatically substituted, put it into double quotes"$variable". not semiquotes '$variable'.function use variable in semiquotes as written with $

Comment: I tried it with double quotes like this```Copy-Item "$PSScriptRoot\Data\AutoUnattend.xml" "C:\ESD\Deployment\Autounattend.xml"
    Copy-Item "$PSScriptRoot\Data\AutoUnattend.xml" "C:\ESD\Mount\Windows\Windows\Panther\Autounattend.xml"  
    Write-Host "Answer file named AutoUnnatend.xml created." -ForeGround DarkRed``` but it still complains

Comment: after changing to doublequotes, what the error message is on screen?

Comment: `Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder
Project\Scripts\Data\AutoUnattend.xml' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\Answerfile.ps1:64 char:5
+     Copy-Item "$PSScriptRoot\Data\AutoUnattend.xml" "C:\ESD\Deploymen ...
+     
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Admin\...utoUnattend.xml:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand`

Comment: I don't understand this is how I have it written
```Copy-Item "$PSScriptRoot\Data\AutoUnattend.xml" "C:\ESD\Deployment\Autounattend.xml"
    Copy-Item "$PSScriptRoot\Data\AutoUnattend.xml" "C:\ESD\Mount\Windows\Windows\Panther\Autounattend.xml"  
    Write-Host "Answer file named AutoUnnatend.xml created." -ForeGround DarkRed```
double quotes

Comment: Do this  (gci "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\Data\AutoUnattend.xml").FullName  and write there result

Comment: Result
`gci : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder
Project\Scripts\Data\AutoUnattend.xml' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\Answerfile.ps1:65 char:7
+      (gci "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder  ...
+       
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Admin\...utoUnattend.xml:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFound
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Comment: Seems like file is not present.. or it is hidden file?

Comment: No not hidden there is a Folder named "Data" in the root directory with the AutoUnnatend.xml file inside it. I have  added a screenshot of the directory above.

Comment: open propertys of file  "AutoUnnatend.xml" in windows gui, tab to 'security', check field "object name"/// is it eq with 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\Data\AutoUnattend.xml'???

Comment: Object name:
`C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Data\AutoUnattend.xml`

Comment: "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Data\AutoUnattend.xml" is not eqevalent of this "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\Data\AutoUnattend.xml" change path to correct!

Comment: $DataFolderPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Data

@FletcherF1 This points to the directory and it still gives an error.   just echoed the path. It shows the same as this C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Data\

Comment: I'l check on my computer whats you write earler "$ScriptPath="$PSScriptRoot\Scripts"
$BinaryPath="$PSScriptRoot\Binaries"
$DataFolderPath="$PSScriptRoot\Data" Everything works fine! run only this part of code in your session and check the results?