# How do I reference multiple paths in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am writing a script that pulls from multiple directories located at the root folder of the script. When I use this:

```
$ScriptPath="$PSScriptRoot\Scripts"
$BinaryPath="$PSScriptRoot\Binaries"
$DataFolderPath="$PSScriptRoot\Data"
```

PowerShell complains about 2 of the 3 paths saying they can't be found.

I also tried this but no luck.

```
$ScriptPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Scripts
$BinaryPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Binaries
$DataFolderPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Data
```

Comment: Please include the code where you actually use these paths and exact error message you get.

Comment: `Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Scripts` -> `Join-Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath Scripts`

Comment: Have you tried doing `Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -Recurse` to verify that your script sees the folders the way you'd like to see them?

Comment: Here is my more detailed post with the errors and code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576276/powershell-script-will-not-recognize-paths-i-am-using?noredirect=1#comment117702168_66576276

Comment: @zett42 I have posted the code you requested.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
$ScriptPath=$PSScriptRoot+"\Scripts"
$BinaryPath=$PSScriptRoot+"\Binaries"
$DataFolderPath=$PSScriptRoot+"\Data"
```

Comment: I still get the same error stating the script cant find the path because it does not exist. If I use the literal path it works but on another computer the path would be different so thats not useful to do. Which is why I need to reference the root directory.

Comment: So I got it working but I just consolidated all the scripts into one main one  So I didn't really fix it just worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running this?

This...`$PSScriptRoot`, will only be populated when you run the full script, not when you run this in the ISE/VSCode, or other editor pane window.

Lastly, `$PSScriptRoot`, as documented...

---

> About Automatic Variables
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1
>
> PSScriptRoot  Contains the full path to the script that invoked

---

... thus, if you are not in a source directory with that set of named subfolders, then you should expect this to fail.

If you want this to work, then you must check for the existence of the subfolders before you begin, and if not already there, then, your script should create them, then run the rest of your code.